# javascript dates interpolation

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have a code example:

```
var input = [{"date":"2013-02-15","price":4604931},{"date":"2014-02-18","price":"3538800.00"}],
chart = []; 

input.each(function(c){     
    chart.push({
       "x"  : c.date,
       "y"  : Math.round(c.price)
    });
});
```

But I need also the dates in my chart array between first index (input[0].date) in input and the latest one.

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What price do you want to show for those missing dates? This may be a feature of the graphing library you intend to use... have you got any in mind?

Comment: Yes. This array dates will be used in D3.js.

Comment: For example next date will be: "x": 2013-02-15, "y": 0

Comment: ... you mean `"x": 2013-02-16, "y": 0`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add in zero values into a time series in d3.js / JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227991/how-to-add-in-zero-values-into-a-time-series-in-d3-js-javascript)